# How to Attach article related list corresponsing to mail subject in notification email when case is logged from email?

Tags: email-template

When case is logged from email, Notification email is received to the person who logged the case. This notification mail is sent to user with help of workflow which uses standard template. As per my requirement i replaced standard template with custom, as such to embed related article list code in custom template. The embedded related list articles are searched corresponding to subject of the case posted while creating case from email. Everything works fine with test mail. But as soon as try to log case from email id. notification mail fails. I am using   to search all the relative article. Any help regarding mail failure will be appreciable. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check in debug log .I think some clue you might get regarding whats happening?

Comment: Debug log doesn't track Workflow when custom template with Component <knowledge:articleList> is Used. However Workflow works fine with Standard Template. May be it is throwing some exception which perhaps doesn't show up in debug log. Please Help.